# How to know which element throws exception in selenium

Tags: firefox, exception, selenium, webdriver, element

I am using selenium 2.46 (firefox driver) to develop an application. There are a lot of element.click() in my code. Sometimes that elements are not visible or not clickable make the application throws selenium exception.

When i read the exception, it is so generic, there is no information about what element causes problem.

My question is: is there any way that i can know exactly what element (by name or id) cause the problem. 
---Edited: Now i add more detail:
Here is my code

```
try{
  el = webdriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#accountDropdownSelect-menu li")).get(i);
  el.click();
}catch (Exception e){
 throw e;
}

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:16:47'
System info: host: 'aaaaa-virtual-machine', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-45-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_80'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 1.15 seconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'aaaaa-virtual-machine', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-45-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_80'
Session ID: 40a1ff52-7082-46f2-a05b-e43d9eade760
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=40a1ff52-7082-46f2-a05b-e43d9eade760, version=39.0, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

Comment: That will throw an exception by giving information of the element that where we got the exception.

Comment: The exception will give a stack trace which will point to a line number in your application that caused it. I'm not sure what else you could possibly want - the exception gives you enough information to know what you are asking.

Comment: here is the error that i caught

Answer (score 1):

Just wait for visibility and you don't have to read these exceptions :)
Here's the example:

```
public static void waitForVisibilityByXPath(final String xpath) {
(new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut))
        .until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).isDisplayed();
            }
        });
```

}

xpath  -  xpath locator for your element.
timeOut - timeout for the waiting

Answer (score 1):

I actually have the same problem. What I'm doing is:

1.) Simply do a `System.out.println("some text that identifies your element.click()")` after every `element.click()` function so you know where it throws the exception.

2.) Surround your `element.click()` with try+catch and throw your own exception e.g. `throw New Exception("some text that identifies your element.click()")`

I know it is not very comfortable but I haven't found any other easier solution yet.